# Socialite redirect to Facebook app instead of browser

Tags: android, ios, laravel, facebook, laravel-socialite

I'm using Socialite in Laravel to authenticate users through Facebook in my back-end. The back-end functions like an API and sends the token back to the front-end after authentication so users can access their data using this token.

On desktop this works fine, but when a user uses our mobile application (Android and iOS simple webview frame) they get redirected to a browser when they click the login button. This breaks the user experience, because they have to type in their Facebook credentials, even though they are already logged in on the Facebook app on their phone.

Is there a way to redirect the users to the Facebook app to log in, while still preserving the login flow through the back-end? The easiest option would be to do login in the front-end, but then we would have to send the token to the back-end and I can't imagine any way to do this securely, because people could send any random token to the back-end to authorize themselves.

Comment: i don't know but i guess it's a no! the user has to be connected on the browser!

Comment: No there is not. If there was Facebook we do that automatically

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you can create another Facebook app available only for web